# jdbcTemplate.update send parameter to stored procedure with different type

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, stored-procedures, procedure, jdbctemplate

I have stored procedure with int parameters like this
**" PROCEDURE send_mail.NotReporting(IN forma varchar(20), IN ryear int(4),IN rperiod int(2))..."**
and in spring in repository class I send parameters like this
**"public List notReporting(int il,int ay) {
jdbcTemplate.update("call send_mail.NotReporting(forma,?,?)",il,ay);
..."**

and there is error text in console:

**PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [call send_mail.NotReporting(forma,?,?)]; Data truncation: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: ',ryear,'; nested exception is com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: ',ryear,'**

why the stored procedure see parameters as double?

Comment: Does your variable have a comma?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.